# Is there any notion of pH out of solution?

Tags: acid-base, ph

For example, could one define a $\mathrm{pH}$ for pure acetic acid? It's a weak acid in water, but if someone handed you $1~\mathrm L$ of pure acetic acid, what would its $\mathrm{pH}$ be?

Comment: pH is usually for more or less diluted water solutions. But here is some insight http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/7000/9961

Comment: Is it? Strictly, it's just $-\log_{10}{\left[\ce{H+}\right]}$, right? Acetic acid may be a bad example, since I would think it wouldn't auto-ionize, but in general, if any solvated proton is present, I would think a $\mathrm{pH}$ could be defined, even if it wasn't particularly useful.

Comment: Edited, but it simply doesn't work the same in other situations.

Comment: @Brian It does auto-ionize, but in pure CH3COOH  will [CH3COOH2+]  be more important then concentration of acid itself? In what context?

Comment: [H0 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammett_acidity_function) is used is such cases.

Comment: This answer is also related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/5741/9961

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [IUPAC definition of pH](http://goldbook.iupac.org/P04524.html) is:

> The quantity pH is defined in terms of the activity of hydrogen(1+) ions (hydrogen ions) in solution:
>
> $pH = − lg [a(H^+)] = − lg [m(H^+) γ_m (H^+) / m^⦵]$
>
> where a$(\ce{H+})$ is the activity of hydrogen ion (hydrogen 1+) in aqueous solution, $(\ce{H+})$(aq), $γ_m(\ce{H+})$ is the activity coefficient of $\ce{H+}$(aq) (molality basis) at molality m$(\ce{H+})$, and m$^⦵ = 1$ mol kg $^{−1}$ is the standard molality.

So since the definition specifically refers to "aqueous solution", pH is undefined unless an aqueous solution is being considered.

There would be a p[H+] in pure acetic acid based upon the self dissociation of acetic acid, where [H+] is the concentration of hydrogen ions in acetic acid solution, but this is not pH according to the IUPAC definition.

According to [Acid-Base Equilibria in Glacial Acetic Acid. III. Acidity Scale. Potentiometric Determination of Dissociation Constants of Acids, Bases and Salts](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01594a014) *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, 1956, vol. 78, pages 2974–2979:

> the autoprotolysis constant of acetic acid is calculated to be $3.5 \times 10^{-15}$ (pK = 14.45)

Therefore p[H+] = 7.2 for pure acetic acid.

This value is not a measure of acidity, but simply the concentration of solvated hydrogen ions in pure acetic acid.