Why is concentrated acid stronger than dilute acid
Concentrated acid has less water (but still water so no autoprotolysis occurs). Therefore, because there is less water, less acid will dissociate as it needs water. As a result, it will mostly remain molecular. So it will have a lower pH. However, google says in concentrated acid, more acid molecules dissociate and so stronger pH. I dont understand why more acid molecules dissociate.

Huh, you know, it still amazes me people can get there's autoprotolysis is a pure acid, but not that being strong means that its molecules are more acidic than hydronium ions.

But autoprotolysis does make them even stronger.

I don't see how it helps, at least you did think about it. BTW it's a duplicate, I just didn't find the right target yet.

Can you send a link then of the original post as I cant find anything

related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/176536/can-acid-base-reaction-occur-if-two-compounds-one-acidic-and-one-basic-are-add https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135162/does-pure-hcl-without-water-is-an-acid

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6997/ph-range-outside-conventional-0-14

Oh, I think the best dupe target is here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78844/a-question-about-acidity

Consider formatting guides for texts and formulas/equations/expressions

Even in 100% H2SO4 there's still water, even a trace of unprotonated H2O. That's because it essentially dehydrates itself to H2S2O7.


When we increase concentration of a strong acid like $\ce{H2SO4}$, more $\ce{H+(aq)}$ ions is present and pH decrease.
At significant content of the acid, H3O+(aq) activity coefficients stops decreasing and starts steeply raise above 1.  $\gamma(\ce{H3O+(aq))}$ is reportedly about 20 for 10-12 M HCl.
pH progressively stops being well defined, as medium stops being water based as it starts being acid based.
At some point, when there is molar ratio $\ce{H2SO4 : H2O}$ $1 : 1$, there is mostly just $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{HSO4-}$, with traces of $\ce{H2O}$, $\ce{H3O+}$, $\ce{H2SO4}$, $\ce{H3SO4+}$. Activity of $\ce{H3O+}$  is already "above the roof".
With even more $\ce{H2SO4}$, $\ce{H3O+}$ stops being the major acidity factor, as H2SO4(l) is much more acidic than H3O+.
It furthermore undergos auto-dissociation as many protic solvents:

$\ce{2 H2SO4 <=> H3SO4+ + HSO4-}$


H3SO4+ is obviously much stronger acid than $\ce{H2SO4}$, but is just minor component.
Some traces of $\ce{H2O}$ is still present even in pure $\ce{H2SO4}$ due dimerization: $\ce{2 H2SO4 <=> HS2O7- + H3O+}$. Note that $\ce{H2S2O7}$ with the Hammett function value $H_0 \approx -15$ is about 1000 times stronger acid than $\ce{H2SO4}$ with $H_0 \approx -12$.



Why does hydrogen ion concentration increase as concentration increases. I thought that would reduce amount of water hence amount of dissociation.

More $\ce{H2SO4}$ = more $\ce{H3O+}$, while there is still bigger molar amount of water than sulfuric acid. There is the equilibrium shifted far, far right:
$$\ce{H2SO4(aq) + H2O <=>> HSO4-(aq) + H3O+(aq)}$$

Are you saying when the acid and water become equivalent, all the water is turned to h3o so there is only trace while in dilute, only some of all the water is turned to h2o meaning in dilute strong acid solution, there is much more h2o molecules

Rather equimolar. And yes, you like repeat the obvious, paraphrasing what I have said.
If you consistently mistype element symbols and charges, chemists will think you are either careless or ignorant or both and they will not take it lightly.

And when all the h2o gets turned to h30, is that when it becomes pure liquid h2so4 and then autoprotlysis starts to occur

Mostly $\ce{H3O+}$, $\ce{HSO4-}$, $\ce{H2SO4}$, and some  $\ce{H3SO4+}$ and $\ce{HS2O7-}$, and very traces of $\ce{H2O}$.

Also where would 98% h2so4 be on scale. Would it be where it is nearly 1:1 molar ratio.

You cannot be serious, asking such a question. Do your homework.

A small table addendum:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{The molar ratio } \\ \ce{H2SO4 : H2O} & \text{Major entities} & \text{Minor entities} & \text{Trace entities} \\
\hline
0.001 & \ce{H2O} & \ce{H3O+ + HSO4- \\ + SO4^2-} & \\
\hline
0.05 & \ce{H2O + H3O+ \\ + HSO4-} & \ce{SO4^2-} & \ce{H2SO4} \\
\hline
1\ (84.5\%) & \ce{H3O+ + HSO4-} & \ce{H2O + H2SO4} & \ce{SO4^2- + HS2O7-} \\
\hline
9\ (98\%) & \ce{H2SO4 + HSO4-} & \ce{H3O+ + HSO4- \\ + HS2O7-} & \ce{H2O + SO4^2- \\ + HS2O7- + H3SO4+} \\
\hline
\infty\ (100\%) & \ce{H2SO4} & \ce{H3O+ + HS2O7- \\ + H3SO4+ + HSO4-} & \ce{H2O  \\  + H2S2O7   + SO3} \\
\hline
\text{The molar ratio } \\ \ce{SO3 : H2SO4 } & & & \\
\hline
0.5 & \ce{H2SO4 + H2S2O7} & \ce{HSO4- + HS2O7- \\ + H3O+ + H3SO4+} & \ce{H2O + H3SO4+ \\ + SO3} \\
\hline
\end{array}

@Fritzy123 If it was dissociated, I would write it as HSO4- or SO4^2-.. //  Also, delete some of you outdated comments, or mods might move the comments to a chat or delete them.

H2SO4 or even H3SO4+ are much more aggressive H+ donors than H3O+. In H2SO4 + HNO3 mixture, it is different. The acting nitration agent is the nitryl cation NO2^+,  formed by H2SO4 + HNO3 -> HSO4- + H2O + NO2+ // But that should be independent question.

If an acid is not a stronger donor of H+ than H3O+, it is not a strong acid.

There is, and it is your homework to find it.

So conc acid being molecules affects their properties making them for e.g great oxidizers. Also so it is accurate that H2SO4 when conc be represented as an entire molecule in reactions

That is true. But H3SO4+, H2NO3+ or NO2^+ are important reactive agents, minor by concentration, but with high thermodynamic activity.  E.g. NO2^+ is the nitration agent in H2SO4 + HNO3 mixture at synthesis nitrocompounds.

By that is true do you mean to both questions (about peoperties and in reactions)

Both cases. With the note that neutral molecules are major, but not the most thermodynamically reactive species.

I have searched a lot but It wont give me info on a reacting agent. What is it and what are  thermodynamically active species

Protonization: H3SO4+ > H2S2O7 > H2SO4 > H3O+ / Nitration: NO2+ > H2NO3+ > HNO3 // Specieas being more TD reactive (not active ) are those with more negative standard reaction Gibbs energy,

Be aware that SE sites are not forums or chats (even if they do have separate chat rooms). It is a Q/A site, with comments not to be abused for above activities. Comments should be closely related to the Q/A, asking for content clarification,  suggesting improvement, or providing minor info, like links  to referred materials.

I'll answer this in what I think is a simpler way than Poutnik. The point being there are multiple concepts being questioned.

For an aqueous acid/base reaction we're considering a reaction where an acid, HA, neutralizes a base, BOH, creating a water molecule, like:
$$ \ce{HA + BOH <=> H2O + BA}$$

Now consider a "concentrated acid" versus a "dilute acid." Typically a trained chemist would consider this to be a reflection of the molarity of the acid. Thus a 0.1 molar solution is more concentrated than a 0.0001 molar solution. (There are polyprotic acids like sulfuric and phosphoric acids that have multiple protons which can react. In this situation the concept of normality comes into play.)

The concept of "stronger". It has two meaning depending on the context. It can mean greater normality, or it can mean that there is a difference in the $\ce{K_a}$ of the acids. Thus again a 0.1 molar hydrochloric acid is a stronger acid solution than a 0.0001 molar solution. But a chemist would typically think of hydrochloric acid being a "stronger" acid than acetic acid because of the greater $\ce{K_a}$ value of hydrochloric acid. Context however may mean that a 0.1 molar acetic acid solution is a "stronger" acidic solution than 0.0001 molar hydrochloric acid solution.

The $\ce{K_a}$ values are for "dilute" aqueous solutions. But $\ce{H3O^+}$ cations and $\ce{OH^-}$ anions don't just float around in aqueous solutions as independent ions. The ions are both surrounded hydration spheres made up of layers of polarized water molecules. Basically "dilute" means that these hydration spheres are separated by so much bulk water that they don't interact with one another. The "activity coefficient" for an ion is a reflection of the interaction that occurs between hydration spheres as the concentration increases.

Lastly the "strength" of an acid solution isn't generally considered to be just a matter of the hydronium ion ($\ce{H3O^+}$) concentration per se.  This is particularly true for concentrated acids like sulfuric, phosphoric, and glacial acetic acid. These concentrated acids are liquid so they have molarities and normalities, but they contain little water so they are not "aqueous" solutions per se.  However activity coefficients can be used to calculate the various equilibria since there is some water. Note also since they can react with a lot of base, they are considered to be strongly acidic.

Consider two different concentrated acids which are 18 normal with little water. The activity coefficients for hydronium and hydroxide will be different in the two different acids since they would be different medium.

The autoprotolysis of water is a fairly weak reaction. In analytical chemistry you'd try to choose the indicators and the concentrations of the acid and base such that the autoprotolysis of water could be ignored. Remember chemistry isn't like mathematics where trillions of significant figures of $\ce{\pi}$ are consequential. Typically in chemistry three significant figures is good work, and four is excellent.


